# How do I get access to a variable without nested callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a simple nested callback utilizing the Node FileSystem module and I'm having a hard time trying to get access to a variable that I feel is only made available due to the scope chain.  My goal is to reduce nested callbacks as much as possible.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var directory = '/Users/johndoe/desktop/temp';

fs.readdir(directory, function(err, files) {
  files.forEach(function(file) {
    var filePath = directory + "/" + file;
    fs.readFile(filePath, function(err, data) {
      // I have access to filePath variable here.  This works just fine.
      console.log(filePath);
    });
  });
});
```

But this is what I would like to write instead:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var directory = '/Users/johndoe/desktop/temp';

fs.readdir(directory, processFiles);

function processFiles(err, files) {
  files.forEach(function(file) {
    var filePath = directory + "/" + file;
    fs.readFile(filePath, processSingleFile);
  });
}

function processSingleFile(err, data) {
  // how do I get the filePath variable here?
  console.log(filePath);
}
```

How do I get the filePath variable here in the second example?

Comment: just use `console.log(data);` in your `processSingleFile` function. :)

Comment: Use promises to reduce nested callbacks and chain the request

Comment: You can use a global variable.

Comment: @AdityaParab, `data` is the contents of the file, not the name of the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass `filePath` as the first parameter to `processSingleFile` by binding it.

```
function processFiles(err, files) {
  files.forEach(function(file) {
    var filePath = directory + "/" + file;
    fs.readFile(filePath, processSingleFile.bind(this, filePath));
  });
}

function processSingleFile(filePath, err, data) {
  console.log(filePath);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `processSingleFile` to  a `function returning function` and pass variable `filePath` as a variable to that. Like bellow

```
function processSingleFile(filePath) {
  return function(err, data){
    console.log(filePath);
    console.log(data);
  }
}
```

call it like bellow

```
fs.readFile(filePath, processSingleFile(filePath));
```

Comment: That's a nested callback, you just nested it in a different function.

Comment: @RaymondChen I don't think this nesting is bad. It's just a wrapper.

Comment: @RaymondChen technically the solution you accepted which binds a function is just another way of scoping it. What happens internally is it becomes a wrapper function to the original function and passes the arguments differently. So any solution you use will have some sort of scoping.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Of course it's scoping. But binding is scoping without using a nested function (because for some reason the OP doesn't like nested functions).

Answer (score 0):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var directory = '/Users/johndoe/desktop/temp';

fs.readdir(directory, processFiles);

// declaring filePath outside to allow scope access
var filePath;

function processFiles(err, files) {
  files.forEach(function(file) {
    filePath = directory + "/" + file;
    fs.readFile(filePath, processSingleFile);
  });
}

function processSingleFile(err, data) {
  // You can access filePath here
  console.log(filePath);
}
```

Comment: Mind you, I have just started working with node, so I can not say if this is the right way of doing it

Comment: That doesn't work once you have more than one file in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
function processFiles(err, files) {
  files.forEach(function(file) {
    var filePath = directory + "/" + file;
    fs.readFile(filePath, function(err,data){
        processSingleFile(data,filePath);
    });
  });
}

function processSingleFile(data, filePath) {
  // You can access filePath here
  console.log(filePath);
}
```